# After switching to the different bootstrap tabs the javascript vlc function not calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, vlc

I am trying to embed the vlc plugin with the bootstrap tabs.After switchng the different bootstrap tabs 
    i am trying to call the vlc javascript functions. But it is messing when i try to call the function.

Here is my code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video panel</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body onload="mainplay()">
    <div class="container">
        <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <h1>Video panel</h1>
            <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" id="hometab">Home</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" id="profiletab">Profile</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#timeline" data-toggle="tab" id="timetab">Timeline</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content"> <br/> <br/>
            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="home">
                <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
                    version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
                    width="640"
                    height="480"
                    id="vlcmain"
                    autoplay="true"
                    windowless="false"
                    toolbar="true"
                    text="waiting for video">
                </embed>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
                <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
                    version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
                    width="640"
                    height="480"
                    id="vlcsub"
                    autoplay="true"
                    windowless="false"
                    toolbar="true"
                    text="waiting for video">
            </embed>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="timeline">
                <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
                    version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
                    width="640"
                    height="480"
                    id="vlcdelayed"
                    autoplay="true"
                    windowless="false"
                    toolbar="true"
                    text="waiting for video">
                </embed>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            function mainplay(){
                var vlcmain= document.getElementById('vlcmain');
                var vlcsub= document.getElementById('vlcsub');
                var vlcdelayed= document.getElementById('vlcdelayed');

                $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                        var target = $(e.target).attr("href");

                    if(target=='#home'){
                        if(vlcmain){
                            vlcsub.playlist.stop();
                            alert(vlcsub.input.state);

                            vlcdelayed.playlist.stop();
                            alert(vlcdelayed.input.state);

                            vlcmain.playlist.add('http://127.0.0.1/vlctest/lua.mp4');
                            vlcmain.playlist.play();
                        }
                    }

                    if(target=='#profile'){
                        if(vlcsub){

                            vlcsub.playlist.add('http://127.0.0.1/vlctest/video1.mp4');
                            vlcsub.playlist.play();
                        } 
                    }

                    if(target=='#timeline'){
                        if(vlcdelayed){

                            vlcdelayed.playlist.add('http://127.0.0.1/vlctest/lua.mp4');
                            vlcdelayed.playlist.play();
                        } 
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically my requirement is:-

There are 3 tabs `home,profile,timeline`, in those three tabs i embedded the three VLC web plugins with different ids.

And my desired functionality is something like this
    when i am playing the `home` tab video, before playing the `home` tab video, the remaining tabs video `profile, timeline` has to go
    in `stop state`.

Like that only when i play the `profile` tab video, the remaining tabs `home,timeline` video has to go in `stop state`.

The same goes to `timeline` tab also.

As of now (I dont know at what extent it is correct way to do) when i click on `profile` tab and go back to `home` tab it is able to stop the `profile`
    tab video and it starts the `home` tab video but for `timeline` tab video it is giving the error.

I tried different ways to achieve this but it is not able to give the desired results.

Please anyone help me on this and suggest me how to do this?

Thanks in advnace.

Comment: might be its because of the other tabs have display:none property can you make fiddle ?

Comment: It is not possible to embed the vlc plugin..

Comment: just try by giving all tab active class/ or display block property and tell is it working after clicking on tabs btn?

Comment: no it is not working..

Comment: can u share a link ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18711/

Comment: but tat is not completely working